# Inserir o gráfico de linha no segundo eixo y com base nos outros eixos (x e y)

Tags: r, ggplot2

Preciso criar um gráfico com 3 eixos. O eixo **x** será o **volume**, o eixo **y à esquerda** será a **área** e o eixo **y à direita** será o valor da **temperatura** que foi obtida considerando a relação de volume e área. Assim, para cada combinação de volume e área têm-se um valor de temperatura obtido.

A intenção é que o gráfico seja composto por linhas horizontais partindo de cada área. Desta forma, para cada área é possível ver a progressão da temperatura a medida que o volume aumenta.

Eu consegui construir minimamente o painel do gráfico mas não consegui lançar os dados da temperatura considerando a área e o volume como referência.

```
  dados %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = volume, y = area))+
  geom_line(colour = 'blue', orientation = "x") +
  scale_y_continuous(sec.axis = sec_axis(~./100, name = "Temperatura")) +
  labs(title = NULL,
       subtitle = NULL,
       y = "Area (m²)", x = "Volume (m³)", colour = "") +
  theme_ipsum() +
  theme(
    legend.position="bottom",
    axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size = 16, face = "plain", hjust = 0.5),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size = 16, face = "plain", hjust = 0.5),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 20, face = "plain", hjust = 0.5))
```

Os meus dados são esses:

```
> dput(dados)
structure(list(area = c(20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 
20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 
40L, 40L, 40L, 40L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 60L, 
60L, 60L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 80L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 
100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 100L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 120L, 
120L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 
140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 
140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 
140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 
140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 140L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 
160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 
160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 
160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 
160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 160L, 
160L, 160L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 
180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 
180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 
180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 
180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 180L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 200L, 
200L, 200L, 200L), volume = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 
20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 
33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 
46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 
10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 
23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 
49L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 
13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 
26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 
39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 
16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 
29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 
42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 
19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 
32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 
45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 
9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 
22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 
35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 
48L, 49L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 
38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 
1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 
15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 
28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 
41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 
18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 
31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 
8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 
21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 
34L, 35L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 44L, 45L, 46L, 
47L, 48L, 49L, 50L), temperatura = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 
0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.03, 0.04, 
0.07, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 
0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.08, 0.06, 0.11, 0.13, 0.13, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 0.14, 
0.07, 0.14, 0.17, 0.19, 0.19, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.21, 
0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 
0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 
0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 
0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.21, 0.08, 0.16, 0.21, 0.23, 0.24, 0.25, 
0.26, 0.26, 0.26, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 0.27, 
0.09, 0.18, 0.24, 0.27, 0.29, 0.3, 0.31, 0.32, 0.32, 0.32, 0.33, 
0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 
0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 
0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 
0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.34, 0.09, 0.2, 0.27, 0.31, 0.33, 
0.35, 0.36, 0.37, 0.37, 0.38, 0.38, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.39, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4, 
0.4, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 
0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.41, 0.1, 
0.22, 0.29, 0.34, 0.37, 0.39, 0.4, 0.41, 0.42, 0.43, 0.44, 0.44, 
0.45, 0.45, 0.45, 0.46, 0.46, 0.46, 0.46, 0.46, 0.46, 0.47, 0.47, 
0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 
0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 
0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.47, 0.11, 0.23, 0.31, 0.36, 0.4, 0.42, 
0.44, 0.46, 0.47, 0.48, 0.49, 0.49, 0.5, 0.5, 0.51, 0.51, 0.52, 
0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.53, 0.53, 0.53, 0.53, 0.53, 0.53, 0.53, 0.54, 
0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 
0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54, 0.54
)), row.names = c(NA, 500L), class = "data.frame")
```

Como inserir a temperatura para cada combinação de área e volume?

(Imagino que possa ficar poluído esse gráfico com tantas linhas, mas depois que resolver essa dificuldade que estou tendo, pretendo dividir a quantidade de áreas e construir vários gráficos com intervalos menores de áreas)

Comment: Benvinda ao StackOverflow em Português! Acredito que esteja utilizando esta página como referência https://r-graph-gallery.com/line-chart-dual-Y-axis-ggplot2.html Porém, com seus dados a visualização fica prejudicada, porque há muita variabilidade. Se seguir o link, só ajustar a escala de temperatura.

Comment: @DanielIkenaga obrigada! Ainda não deu certo, mas continuarei tentando fazer a alteração.

Comment: "Eu consegui construir minimamente o painel do gráfico mas não consegui lançar os dados da temperatura considerando a área e o volume como referência." Você não incluiu nenhuma geometria para os dados (p.e., `geom_line`).

Comment: @CarlosEduardoLagosta eu editei o código: inseri na terceira linha `geom_line(colour = 'blue', orientation = "x") +` mas não fica como eu gostaria pois não separa as linhas por área. Não consigo fazer esse vínculo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se entendi direito o que deseja:

- calcule a relação entre a escala de área e a de temperatura
- use área como variável agrupadora, para ter uma curva para cada
- gere dois grupos de linhas, um para área, outro para temperatura

```
library(ggplot2)

# coeficientes para converter escala da temperatura para escala da área
a <- min(dados$area)
b <- diff(range(dados$area))/diff(range(dados$temperatura))

ggplot(dados, aes(x = volume, group = area, color = area))+
  geom_line(aes(y = area), linetype = "dashed") +
  geom_line(aes(y = a + b*temperatura), size = 1.1) +
  scale_y_continuous("Area (m²)",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~ (. - a)/b, "Temperatura (°C)")) +
  scale_color_distiller(palette = "Dark2") +
  labs(x = "Volume (m³)") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position = "n")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Carlos Eduardo, seria isso sim o que procuro! A única dúvida que fiquei é a seguinte: cada cor desse gráfico simboliza uma das áreas analisadas, então a escala em y a esquerda (referente as áreas) não seria necessária, certo?

Comment: Por escala quer dizer legenda? O gráfico que postei é um exemplo de como resolver a dúvida que postou, personalize como preferir. Se quiser legenda, adicione as opções `guide = "legend", breaks = rev(unique(dados$area))` à `scale_color_distiller` (e edite a opção `legend.position` para `left` se quiser do lado esquerdo).

Comment: Era a escala mesmo! Carlos Eduardo, muito obrigada pelo auxílio, me ajudou muito!